# Verbs for bending and turning

Tags: word-choice

I'm having some difficulty with the various verbs that exist for bending and turning and could really use some insight into them:
曲がる - Intransitive
曲げる - Transitive
回る - Intransitive
回す - Transitive

JDIC additionally lists 転じる, which I'm not familiar with.

I get the feeling that the 曲-based ones are more of a "bending" or "one-time turning" concept while the 回-based ones are more of a turning/rotating/spinning concept.  More cyclical, you know?

Comment: Your feeling is perfectly right ;)

Comment: For a 熟語, `[回転]{かいてん}` also means "rotate/revolve".

Comment: Well, that's pretty straightforward, then.  Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you find out what the difference is between 回る and 廻る, by the way ;)

Comment: Vaguely related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8187/reading-%E6%8D%BB%E3%82%8B-when-is-it-%E3%81%AD%E3%81%98%E3%82%8B-or-%E3%81%B2%E3%81%AD%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 3):

According to みんなの日本語初級I Lessons 14 and 23 曲がる means to turn (around the corner):

> すみません。 あの信号を右へ曲がってください。
>
> Excuse me. Please turn to the right on that traffic light.

and 回す means to turn something (like a leaver or knob):

> 音が小さいですね。
>
> …このつまみを右へ回すと、大きくなります。
>
> The volume is low.
>
> ...If you turn this knob to the right it will go up.

On the other hand, according to the [電子辞書](http://www.jisho.org/) 曲げる (Transitive) means to bend something, like a steel bar or your finger.

Also 回る (Intransitive) refers to something that rotates on it's own, right now I can think of a plane's propeller or some other mechanical part, like:

飛行機のプロペラが回っています。

Plane's propeller is rotating.

I hope this was helpful to you.